# Need design suggestions for nested conditions

Tags: java

I need to write the logic with many conditions(up to 30 conditions) in one set of rule with many if else conditions and it could end in between or after all the conditions.

Here is the sample code I have tried with some possible scenario. This gives me result but doesn't look good and any minor miss in one condition would take forever to track.

What I have tried so far is, Take out common conditions and refactored to some methods. Tried creating interface with conditions and various set would implement it.

If you have any suggestion to design this, would help me. Not looking for detailed solution but even a hint would be great.

```
private Boolean RunCondition(Input input) {
    Boolean ret=false;
    //First if
    if(input.a.equals("v1")){
        //Somelogic1();
        //Second if
        if(input.b.equals("v2"))
            //Third if
            if(input.c >1)
                //Fourth if
                //Somelogic2();
                //Go fetch key Z1 from database and see if d matches.
                if(input.d.equals("Z1"))                        
                        System.out.println("Passed 1");
                    // Fourth Else
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Failed at fourth");
                    }

            //Third Else
            else{
                if(input.aa.equals("v2"))
                    System.out.println("Failed at third");
                }
        //Second Else
        else{
            if(input.bb.equals("v2"))
                System.out.println("Failed at second");
            }
    }
    //First Else
    else{
        if(input.cc.equals("v2"))
            System.out.println("Failed aat first");
        }

    return ret;
}

public class Input {
    String a;
    String b;
    int c;
    String d;
    String e;       
    String aa;
    String bb;
    String cc;
    String dd;
    String ee;  

}
```

Comment: It would be much easier if you a) indented it sensibly, b) used `else if`.

Comment: This is about neither oop nor design patterns. It's just about writing procedural code.

Comment: I think to get the right answer for your problem you will need to explain how you end up with this logic. Maybe you can use the Filter design pattern or the right OO can solve your problem

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: @Mzf, I would end up storing the results in database and display to user that the conditions result was pass or fail.

Answer (score 1):

The flow is complicated because you have a normal flow, plus many possible exception flows when some of the values are exceptional (e.g. invalid).

This is a perfect candidate to be handled using a **try/catch/finally** block.

Your program can be rewritten into following:

```
private Boolean RunCondition(Input input) {
    Boolean ret=false;
    try {
        //First if
        if(!input.a.equals("v1")) {
            throw new ValidationException("Failed aat first");
        }
        //Somelogic1();

        //Second if
        if(!input.b.equals("v2")) {
            throw new ValidationException("Failed at second");
        }
        //Somelogic2()

        //Third if
        if(input.c<=1) {
            throw new ValidationException("Failed at third");
        } 

        //Fourth if
        //Somelogic2();
        //Go fetch key Z1 from database and see if d matches.
        if(!input.d.equals("Z1")) {
            throw new ValidationException("Failed at fourth");
        }
        System.out.println("Passed 1");

    } catch (ValidationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Where you can define your own `ValidationException` (like below), or you can reuse some of the existing standard exception such as `RuntimeException`

```
class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {

    public ValidationException(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

You can read more about this in

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: This is interesting option. I was hesitant to use Exception as it will eat up memory but will give it a shot.

Comment: Exceptions aren't necessary, and shouldn't be used like this. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41751365/3788176) for a slight variation on this, which is much simpler and faster.

Comment: The dogma is that exceptions should not be used for flow control and so there are stylistic reasons why this solution should not be adopted.

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate class for the condition:

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class App 
{
    static class Condition<T> {
        final int idx;
        final T compareValue;
        public Condition(final int idx, final T compareValue) {
            this.idx = idx;
            this.compareValue = compareValue;
        }
        boolean satisfies(final T other) {
            return other.equals(compareValue);
        }

        int getIdx() {
            return idx;
        }
    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        final List<Condition<String>> conditions = new ArrayList<Condition<String>>();
        conditions.add(new Condition<String>(1, "v1"));
        conditions.add(new Condition<String>(2, "v2"));
        final List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("v1", "xyz"));
        boolean ret = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
            if (!conditions.get(i).satisfies(inputs.get(i)))
            {
                System.out.println("failed at " + conditions.get(i).getIdx());
                ret = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ret=" + ret);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of each rule check as an object, or as a Strategy that returns whether or not the rule passes. Each check should implement the same IRuleCheck interface and return a RuleCheckResult, which indicates if the check passed or the reason for failure.

```
public interface IRuleCheck
{
   public RuleCheckResult Check(Input input);
   public String Name();
 }

public class RuleCheckResult
{
    private String _errorMessage;
    public RuleCheckResult(){}//All Good
    public RuleCheckResult(String errorMessage)
    {
         _errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    public string ErrorMessage()
    {
         return _errorMessage;
    }
    public Boolean Passed()
    {
       return _errorMessage == null || _errorMessage.isEmpty();
    }

}

public class CheckOne implements IRuleCheck
{
       public RuleCheckResult Check(Input input)
       {
          if (input.d.equals("Z1"))
          {
             return new RuleCheckResult();//passed
          }
          return new RuleCheckResult("d did not equal z1");
        }
       public String Name();
}
```

Then you can simply build a list of rules and loop through them, 
and either jump out when one fails, or compile a list of failures.

```
for (IRuleCheck check : checkList) 
{
    System.out.println("checking: " + check.Name());
    RuleCheckResult result = check.Check(input);
    if(!result.Passed())
    {
        System.out.println("FAILED: " + check.Name()+ " - " + result.ErrorMessage());
       //either jump out and return result or add it to failure list to return later.
    }
}
```

And the advantage of using the interface is that the checks can be as complicated or simple as necessary, and you can create arbitrary lists for checking any combination of rules in any order.

Answer (score 1):

[@leeyuiwah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41750400/3788176) has a clear structure of the conditional logic, but exceptions aren't the right tool for the job here.

You shouldn't use exceptions to cope with non-exceptional conditions. For one thing, exceptions are really expensive to construct, because you have to walk all the way up the call stack to construct the stack trace; but you don't need the stack trace at all.

Check out *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 57: "Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions" for a detailed discussion of why you shouldn't use exceptions like this.

A simpler option is to define a little helper method:

```
private static boolean printAndReturnFalse(String message) {
  System.out.println(message);
  return false;
}
```

Then:

```
if(!input.a.equals("v1")) {
  return printAndReturnFalse("Failed aat first");
}
// etc.
```

which I think is a simpler; and it'll be a lot faster.